# Graphql query work well on graphql server but not on client

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I have a resolver for check user login or not

```
 // ______________________________Check if user logged in____________________________________
  @Query((_return) => User, { nullable: true })
  async user(@Ctx() { req }: Context): Promise<User | null | undefined> {
    console.log(req.session.userId)
    if (!req.session.userId) return null;
    else{
      return await User.findOne(req.session.userId)
    }
  }
```

it work on http://localhost:4000/graphql, but when i query on client(React) it return undefined.

code for query at client

```
  const { data, loading, error } = useUserQuery();
  console.log(`data:${data}`)
  console.log(`error:${error}`)
```

i use codegen for generate useUserQuery(), it like

```
export function useUserQuery(baseOptions?: Apollo.QueryHookOptions<UserQuery, UserQueryVariables>) {
        const options = {...defaultOptions, ...baseOptions}
        return Apollo.useQuery<UserQuery, UserQueryVariables>(UserDocument, options);
      }
```

my cookie on client still existing ,but it just not work, how can i fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Apollo query will take a finite amount of time to come back with an answer; that's why when you immediately log `${data}` you get `undefined`.

You can confirm this by logging out the `loading` variable - you'll see it's `true` - the query is "in flight" and `data` will continue to be `undefined` until `loading` goes false.

So a very simple way to handle this might be as in [this Apollo docs example](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/queries/#executing-a-query) - just return early while we're `loading`:

```
const { data, loading, error } = useUserQuery();
if (loading) return 'Loading...';

// At this point we either have an error or data; handle it
console.log(`data:${data}`)
console.log(`error:${error}`)
```

That's fine if you can afford to "stop the world" (or at least the UI) until the data has arrived, but generally I like to get on with rendering as much as I can and "listen" to the `data` with a `useEffect()`, you can then do something once it has become available:

```
const { data, error } = useUserQuery();

useEffect(() => {
  // Always check for an error first:
  if (error) {
    console.log(`error:${error}`)
  }
  
  if (data) {
    // Handle the data
    console.log(`data:${data}`)
  }
}, [data, error]);

...

// Always return the UI
return (
  ...
);
```